# trim sql variant

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-variant

I have column sql variant, which has the following meanings: `100, 150, D1`
I'm trying to convert all numbers in the columns into letters (such as `D1`) according to specific logic in case when. But `150` has spaces and the `CASE WHEN` doesn't work.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
Select  *,
        Case When LTrim(Cast(AttributeValue As NVarchar(Max))) Between 0 And 200 Then 'D1'
             Else 'Other'
        End
From    MyTable As SCR With (NoLock);
```

I tried the following

```
LTRIM(CAST column AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

but now I get error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'D1' to data type int

How can I remove spaces from sql_variant?

Comment: Please show the full query.

Comment: SELECT *, CASE WHEN LTRIM(CAST(AttributeValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) BETWEEN 0 AND 200 THEN 'D1' ELSE AttributeValue END
FROM MyTable AS SCR WITH (NOLOCK)

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing as a `variant` is SQL Server !

Comment: @iDevlop yes there is. sql_variant is a sql-server data type it isn't great to use it but it does exist. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx

Comment: @Matt I learned something today :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your comments edited to use BIGINT due to having larger numbers and leave the column the same if it is not BETWEEN 0 and 400

```
SELECT *
    ,CASE
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(CAST(AttributeValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))) = 1
             AND CAST(LTRIM(CAST(AttributeValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS BIGINT) BETWEEN 0 AND 400 THEN 'D1'
       ELSE AttributeValue
    END
FROM
    MyTable AS SCR WITH (NOLOCK)
```

You can use the `ISNUMERIC()` function to determine which of your `sql_variants` are integers and which are not.

The reason your code is failing isn't because of the trim it is because you are comparing a VARCHAR with an INTEGER so SQL is trying to automatically re cast your final string as an integer which in the case of D1 is not numeric so it causes a conversion error.

Also note that you cannot use `sql_variant` directly in the `ISNUMERIC()` function so cast to a `varchar` first.

Here is an entire example of you to show you how it works:

```
DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE (AttributeValue SQL_VARIANT)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(CAST('     150' AS VARCHAR(100)))
,(CAST('D1' AS VARCHAR(100)))

SELECT *
    ,CASE
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(CAST(AttributeValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))) = 1
             AND CAST(LTRIM(CAST(AttributeValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS INT) BETWEEN 0 AND 200 THEN 'D1'
       ELSE 'Other'
    END
FROM
    @MyTable AS SCR
```

Comment: I posted the whole query. When in where case I choose such rows, where sql_variant column has numbers with spaces, the logic works. But when it select rows like 'D2' I get the error

Comment: @Asakura are you saying that with testing with ISNUMERIC() you are still getting the error or something different can you post what you have tried most recently that gave you the error?

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you! But after I changed my query according to your answer, I faced another problem. As this column is filled by software users, it has some strange values like 20001069307 and now I get error: The conversion of the nvarchar value '20001069307' overflowed an int column. Is there any fix for it?

Comment: I'll write my whole task: I should convert numbers below 400 to letters like D1 according to specific logic, all other different values should remain as they were filled by software users

Comment: @Asakura you can cast as BIGINT instead of INT which allows for larger numbers..  If you need to account for a decimal place then you can use a DECIMAL() instead.

Comment: @Asakura to get them to remain the same in the ELSE section simply put the column name.

Comment: it worked. Thank you very much again, you made my day!

Comment: glad it worked please accept the answer so others know that you got what you needed and the reputation points get assigned here is a link with more information on how/when/why etc if you need. thanks http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -2):

use sql replace function
select replace(columnnName, ' ', '')

Comment: When I use replace I get this error:                            Argument data type sql_variant is invalid for argument 1 of replace function

Comment: @Asakura this wouldn't help you with the conversion issue that you are facing you have to test if the data isnumeric first.  this is just another way of removing spaces but this will remove ALL spaces which happens to be okay in your case.  sql_variant cannot be used in functions so you would have to cast the column to a varchar inside the replace. but again this won't help you with your data conversion error which is why it has 2 downvotes already